# Simple Email Regex Issue

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to combine a couple simple email PCRE regex checks for Postfix. I'll be honest, this is not my area of expertise.

Is there a way to combine the 2? or should they be left separate?

I know I need the < > to be optional, but adding ? to them did nothing.

```
This handles "<yes@aol.com>, <no@aol.com>" format
(?:To|Cc):(?:.+?<.+?[@].+?>){2,}

This handles "yes@aol.com, no@aol.com" format
(?:To|Cc):(?:.+?[@].+?),.{2,}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with optional `<` and `>` on either side of email address:

```
(?:To|Cc):(?:\h*<?\w[^@]*@\S+>?,?){2,}
```

This will match both of these inputs:

```
To: <yes@aol.com>, <no@aol.com>
Cc: yes@aol.com, no@aol.com
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YO7v0m/3)